# Groovy File class putting anti slash instead of slash

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am writting a Groovy script to copy some files from the Jenkins master (Windows) to a slave (Linux). But I encountred a problem: the File class put '\' instead of '/' in the Linux folder path, so it cannot recognize the path. 
The error says that the file is not found:
[image: Jenkins error]

As you can see in the screenshot, the master path is goot the slave path is also good until I pass it to the File class to create the new file.
Here is my Groovy script:

```
def master = build.getRootDir().getAbsolutePath() +"\\"
println "Master path: " + master

def slave = build.getEnvironment(listener).get("WORKSPACE") + "/"
println "Slave path: " + slave


def src = new File(master+'myFile.xml')

hudson.FilePath workspace = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()
File dst = new File("${workspace}/dst.xml")
println(dst)
dst << src.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always replace `\` with `/` in Your $workspace. Remember about 4 x `\`

```
def path = $/\home\sky\asas\file/$

String newPath = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
println "New Path : " + newPath 

[output] New Path : /home/sky/asas/file
```

Comment: I didn't know about the 4* \, Thanks